# How to create windows MSI in separate solution?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

How to Create a MSI for windows Applications which is available in different visual studio solution.

Comment: Can not you add that project in your setup create solution ?

Comment: @Saurabh - Both is possible, see the **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890475/1016343)** below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the **[installer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)** (if not, see **notes** below), **open Visual Studio,** then do the following (at this point, no solution is opened):

1. If you start with a new solution, select **File -> New Project.**
   (In case you want to add the installer project to an existing solution instead, **right click** on
   the solution in the **solution explorer** and choose from the context menu **Add -> New
   Project.**)
2. In the New Project dialog, select **"Other Project Types",** then **"Visual Studio Installer"** and there **"Setup Wizard"** (Alternatively you can also select a Windows setup project or a Web setup project directly - the wizard has the advantage that it will ask you about several items)
3. In the **Setup Wizard,** you can choose whether you want to create a setup for a Windows application or for a Web application. Here, select **Windows application.**
4. Click <kbd>Next ></kbd>. The **"Choose files to include"** dialog appears. 
   This step is important, because here you specify which files you want to add to your installer package. Check the items you need to include - for localized projects I suggest that you add: "Locally copied items, Runtime Implementation, Localized resources, Content files" and "Primary output."
5. Click <kbd>Next ></kbd> again to bring up the last page (**"Create project"** dialog), then click <kbd>Finish</kbd>

You have now a solution with one setup project. Now you can add an existing project (select the solution, right-click and select **"Add existing project"**). After you have done that, right-click on the setup project and select **"Add -> Project Output".** Now you can select the items to be included in your setup project.

If required, you can also add other assemblies via **"Add -> Assembly..."** or, if you have that, you can add merge modules.

---

**Notes**

- You need to install the **extension "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects"** (via Tools -> Extensions and Updates, search it online in the Visual Studio Marketplace) to be able to select the installer as described above
- that the project you have added can be part of a **different solution.**
- The 4 most important properties of a **setup package** are: **Version,** **ProductCode,** **Upgrade code** and **Platform** (default is `x86`). Version is just a number (e.g. `1.0.1`) while the other two properties are GUIDs. If you change the version in the **package properties,** then Visual Studio asks to create a new ProductCode (if you answer the question with **"Yes"** - which is recommended). This allows the Windows installer to distinguish the differrent packages from one another and allows to upgrade a package, because the UpgradeCode isn't changed.
- Additionally, the default value for **RemovePreviousVersions** is `false` - but in most cases you want to change this to `true` (remember what I said before about ProductCode and UpgradeCode): To remove old versions automatically when you install a new version.

Comment: It is solution for the problem, but what if somebody updates the projects that you added previously?

Comment: @koviroli - Simply rebuild all related projects/solutions and as final step select the setup project in the solution explorer, right-click and select "Build". This will collect all related files and add re-create the installer package. To find the built package, right-click on the setup project and select "Open folder in file explorer". Depending on the built configuration, it will be in "Debug" or "Release" - usually one "Setup.exe" and the MSI file in the same directory.

Comment: @koviroli - One more hint: Only if the related projects are included in the solution Visual Studio can detect if there has been changes or not - this is done through Project dependencies. If you just add files from an outside project, you need to build it in the right order by yourself.

Comment: @koviroli thanks for your great answer. I changed the standard setup to Wizard model and follow your steps then the result is successful.

Comment: @Erdogan - You're welcome. FYI, I wrote the answer.